# Multiple java processes in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, process

I am working on a web-based application which is deployed in the Tomcat server. In our local dev enviroemt, when we start the Tomcat server it spawns only one java process which keeps running. However, an issue has been reported in production where the CPU usage for java process has gone up and there are multiple java processes which have  been spawned.

There is no other java application running, so this must have been spawned from Tomcat itself. What is the reason that in our development enviroment there is only one java process while in production multiple java processes have been spawned by Tomcat and how to correct it.

Regards,
    Dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see are most likely multiple threads that the version of top or ps shows on the production box, while you don't see them on the local one.

In production you most likely face a much higher workload, so that requests are served in parallel, while on the local box Tomcat gets away with less threads.

Comment: The scenario is that in the development there is ALWAYS ONE THREAD, but in production there are multiple threads.

Comment: basically , we have created the same load in production as well as development enviroment, but in production there are always multiple threads.

Comment: Are we talking about processes or threads? You'll always have more than one thread, even in development (caps notwithstanding)

Comment: sorry for the confusion, i mean in development there is only one java process whereas in production there are multiple java processed verified from running the ps command.

Comment: What OS are we talking here? If Linux/OSX, try ps -M on the devel box

Answer (score 1):

Unlike Apache HTTPD, Tomcat doesn't spawn processes on its own (it uses multiple threads to serve multiple clients) so you should look elsewhere. For example, how do you deploy your application to the Tomcat. Could it be something like a buggy deployment script?

Also, what other applications run on this Tomcat container?