# Proton CEP creates almost a hundred processes in less than 10 hours

Tags: tomcat, fiware

Our instance of Proton CEP works fine (low cpu usage), but over the course of several hours we find that it creates almost a hundred processes, as seen in the picture below.

[image]

What is causing this; is this OK; and if not, how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

That would be a Tomcat issue that it spawns these processes to scale out its load. In fact, these should be threads and not processes, and Tomcat would manage them for the application. More on similar issues see [Multiple java processes in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631162/multiple-java-processes-in-tomcat).
Hope this helps
- Uri